# Standardising the weights generated from feedforward back propagation NN

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, classification, neural-networks, standardization

I have binary data input to NN. The weights generated by NN are not normalized, i.e., the weights are not the same for every run of the algorithm. How to standardize these weights?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a normalisation problem, it's an artifact of random initialisation of the weights. A simple solution is to run training a few times and pick the weights that minimise your loss function over the different runs.

Comment: Thank you. But can we automate this procedure of finding the best run